# PHP Multiple file upload then attach inline to email via PHPMailer

Tags: php, arrays, loops, file-upload, phpmailer

I'm having a spot of bother with PHPMailer and have searched high and low for this information but nada.

Basically I have a form where the user can upload multiple images which are then saved to a folder on my server, then I need to send an email with the images attached inline at the bottom of the email via PHPMailer.

I can get it to put the first image as inline but the rest of the images do not appear..

Some code:

```
require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

if(count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0){
    //Loop through each file
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
      //Get the temp file path
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

        //Make sure we have a filepath
        if($tmpFilePath != ""){

            //save the filename
            $shortname = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];


            //save the url and the file
            $filePath = "../reports/".$id."/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

            //Upload the file into the temp dir
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {

                $files[] = $shortname;
                //insert into db 
                //use $shortname for the filename
                //use $filePath for the relative url to the file


          $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($filePath, $shortname, $shortname);
          $atts = '<img src="cid:'.$shortname.'">';


            }
          }
    }
}
$mail->Body .= $atts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
$dir2 = opendir('../reports/'.$id);  // Open the directory containing the uploaded files.

$files = array();
while ($files[] = readdir($dir2));
rsort($files);
closedir($dir2);

foreach ($files as $file) {


      if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != 'resources' ){
      $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $file);
      $url = '../reports/'.$id.'/'.$file;
      $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($url, $withoutExt);
      $mail->Body .= '<img src="cid:'.$withoutExt.'">';
      }

}
```